# Select default setting for user from default table if user setting table is empty

Tags: sql-server

my sql is weak and I'm struggling to get the results I want and am sure it's something simple.

I have three tables:

```
user, usersetting and defaultsetting
```

User table columns:

```
UserId | Email
```

UserSetting table columns:

```
UserId | SettingKey | IsEnabled
```

DefaultSetting table columns:

```
SettingKey | IsEnabled
```

A user will only have a record in the usersetting table if they have updated their setting explicitly otherwise they should just get the setting from the defaultSetting table. Settings are either on or off for a user (IsEnabled)

I want to write a query that gets all the users that have setting X (settingKey = x) enabled. If a user does not have a row for setting x in their UserSettings table but the default setting IsEnabled = true then I still want to get a row for that user.

so logically I want to do this

```
Select UserId, Email from User if they have turned setting x on explicitly or setting x defaults to on
```

Answer (score 0):

coalesce is your friend here.

```
Select UserId, Email, coalesce(UserSetting.SettingKey, DefaultSetting.SettingKey) as SettingKey
from User 
left join UserSetting 
on user.userid = UserSetting.userid
left join DefaultSetting 
on UserSetting.SettingKey = DefaultSetting.SettingKey
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I seem to be getting nulls for the SettingKey even though I have two rows in my DefaultSetting table. Is the left join DefaultSetting correct?

Comment: Yes, you want to use the left join, because if no settings are saved, you still want to get the default information from your third table. As for the left join ON part, I'm not 100% sure, because I can't see your data.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, there are currently no rows in the usersettings table and the join is looks right for my tables but SettingKey is always null when what i need is for it to get the key from the DefaultSetting table

Comment: Hi Cam, What the Coalesce command will do is get the first non NULL value from the list. So if you have the usersetting first and then the defaultsetting, it will always pull the first non NULL value. So when the usersetting is NULL it will pull the second value, then once you set the usersetting, it will pull that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I included sample table and data for test

```
create table #Users (UserId int, Email varchar(100))
create table #UserSetting (UserId int, SettingKey varchar(10), IsEnabled int)
create table #DefaultSetting (SettingKey varchar(10), IsEnabled int)

insert into #Users values (1, 'User1')
insert into #Users values (2, 'User2')
insert into #Users values (3, 'User3')

insert into #DefaultSetting values ('default', 1)

insert into #UserSetting values (1, 'pass1', 1)
insert into #UserSetting values (2, 'pass2', 1)


select u.UserId, u.Email, coalesce(us.SettingKey, ds.SettingKey) SettingKey
from #Users u
    left join #UserSetting us on us.UserId = u.UserId and us.IsEnabled = 1
    cross join #DefaultSetting ds
where coalesce(us.SettingKey, ds.SettingKey) = 'pass2'
```

Comment: That's looks good except now I get multiple rows for a user if I add a clause like where settingkey ='x' and they have rows in the UserSetting table. If they have three rows in the UserSettings table for different settings I get three rows for settingkey = 'x'

Comment: @CamLangsford, I don't see any issue. I edited my answer and add sample data for test. If you have any issue please clear the case and provide some sample data in you question.

Comment: Hey thanks. Your data only has one row per user in the usersetting table. If you add another row insert into #UserSetting values (1, 'pass2', 1) then your query will return two rows for that user when there should only be one.

Comment: How come a user can have more than ONE setting? BTW, if you have 2 record for a user, which one you are going to select? Are you saying user can have multiple settings but only one of them is Enabled? if so look at my answer. you just need to add a filter. If not, looks like something is wrong with your design.

Comment: 1 setting per setting key per user, multiple settings. but I think I haven't implemented you solution properly anyway. I actually simplified my design for the question. Let me confirm